# .pac file or manual proxy stopped working with ssh / socks5 and firefox 118

Tags: linux, ssh, firefox, proxy, socks5

Up until updating firefox to 118 my .pac file for automatic proxy configuration was working okay. I'm on linux and the proxy is over ssh with socks5 so first I do

```
ssh -D9999 my.remote.server.com
```

and in my .pac file the `FindProxyForURL( url, host )` function returns either `""` for no proxy or `"SOCKS5 localhost:9999"` for using the ssh/socks5 proxy.

This setup was working perfectly fine, but with firefox 118 it doesn't anymore. When I enter a URL for which the .pac file returns `"SOCKS5 localhost:9999"` the page just hangs.

It doesn't matter if I check or uncheck in `Settings` the box `Proxy DNS when using SOCKS v5`.

If I select `Manual proxy configuration` instead and enter `localhost` and `9999` for all 3 hosts and ports (HTTP proxy, HTTPS proxy, Socks Host) and select `SOCKS v5` the pages don't hang anymore but return a "Secure Connection Failed" error. Again it doesn't matter if `Proxy DNS when using SOCKS v5` is checked or unchecked.

Any ideas what's going on? What changed in Firefox? I haven't been able to find anything in the release notes or what's new pages.

The openssh version is openssh-8.4p1-8.

Update:

It appears the problem disappears on most wifi networks, only one is problematic. Hard to reproduce I guess, so will be difficult to track down...

Comment: There was perhaps some JavaScript change in Firefox 118. If your `FindProxyForURL` is failing, you could debug it using [JavaScript alert](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp).

Comment: The function is perfectly fine actually. Even without a .pac file, manual proxy doesn't work either, it gives me "Secure Connection Failed". The same ssh/socks5/proxy setup worked before though.

Comment: It turns out I only have this problem on a particular wifi network, on another one it works just as before.

Comment: What's different about this network? Different identification?

Comment: I'm not sure. Probably blocks some high ports?